# Delete items from an array inside a nested object

Tags: filter

I have this object (mainArray) and I want to remove 2 items (uniqueItem1, uniqueItem2) from a nested array. As a result, I should get the filtered main object back without the two items. how do I do it?

```
const mainArray = {
    country1: {
        language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    },
    country2: {
        language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
        language2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
    },
    country3: {
        language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', **'uniqueItem1', 'uniqueItem2'**],
    },
};
```

My result should be this:

```
const mainArray = {
        country1: {
            language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        },
        country2: {
            language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
            language2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
        },
        country3: {
            language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mainArray = {
            country1: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3','uniqueItem1'],
            },
            country2: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
                language2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
            },
            country3: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'uniqueItem1', 'uniqueItem2'],
            },
        };

        const removeitems = ['uniqueItem1','uniqueItem2']

        function removeItem(obj, itemtoberemoved){
            
            for(let countrykey in obj) {
                for(let langkey in obj[countrykey] ){

                    for(let removeVal of removeitems){

                        var curIndex = obj[countrykey][langkey].findIndex( (item) => item === removeVal );

                        if(curIndex > -1) {
                            obj[countrykey][langkey].splice(curIndex,1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    removeItem(mainArray, removeitems)
    
    console.log(mainArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to remove country specific item**

```js
    const mainArray = {
            country1: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3','uniqueItem1'],
            },
            country2: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
                language2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
            },
            country3: {
                language1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'uniqueItem1', 'uniqueItem2'],
            },
        };
    /*country specific item remove*/
    const removeitems = {
                                country : 'country3',
                                removeitems : ['uniqueItem1','uniqueItem2'] 
                            }
        
        function removeItem(obj, itemtoberemoved){
            
            for(let countrykey in obj) {
                if( countrykey == itemtoberemoved.country ) {
                    for(let langkey in obj[countrykey] ){

                        for(let removeVal of itemtoberemoved.removeitems){

                            var curIndex = obj[countrykey][langkey].findIndex( (item) => item === removeVal );

                            if(curIndex > -1) {
                                obj[countrykey][langkey].splice(curIndex,1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        removeItem(mainArray, removeitems)
    
    console.log(mainArray)
```